# MVC 3 unobtrusive jquery validate - how to add a Dummy message to Vallidation Summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I get some error messages from the back end service and I want them to be displayed in the Validation Summary control on the page.

I am using MVC 3 and ValidationSummary is not on the page till a validation fails due to unobtrusive stuff i believe.

I looked at the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808327/how-to-read-modelstate-errors-when-returned-by-json) but it does not work with MVC 3.

Does anyone knows how to simply insert an error message in Validation summary control in MVC 3 with all the unobtrusive stuff switched on?

Thanks,

Dexter

Comment: Are you asking how to do remote validation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this [article on Remote Validation](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/mvc-3-and-remote-validation/51) should do the trick.

Of course, you will still need to make sure you print the `ValidationSummary` in your views:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("There are errors that must be fixed:")%>
```